# How to upload images in specifier path to python using Numerical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want my program to upload all the images in a directory using a path , I am using :

```
 for subdirs, dirs, files in os.walk(args.imagesdirectory):  

   for file in files:  

     print("file is ",file)
     path=subdirs+'/'+file
     print("path is ",path)
     img = Image.open(path)
```

so my question is how to make the programm always import the images in this order 0001.jpg then 0002.jpg then 0003.jpg ...ect,  and not in a random way ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you know the names in advance, you could do that with `range()` function.

i.e.

```
for filenum in range(len(files)):
    img = open(filenum + ".jpg")
    ...
```

Also, it's generally better to use `with open(file) as f` then `f = open(file)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using Py3.4 or greater, the pathlib module is very useful for work like this. It's part of the standard distribution.

I have a subdirectory on one of my drives called C:/Camera/Selected. This is how I can list the jpg images in numerical order.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for p in sorted(list(Path('C:/Camera/Selected').glob('*.jpg'))):
...     str(p)
... 
'C:\\Camera\\Selected\\20150320_155849.jpg'
'C:\\Camera\\Selected\\20160905_184732.jpg'
'C:\\Camera\\Selected\\20170717_082735.jpg'
```

In your case, you would have, `img = Image.open(str(p))` within the for loop.